# J packages with sparse matrix algorithms

Tags: sparse-matrix, svd, j

Are there any J packages with sparse matrix algorithms that enhance the functionalities mentioned here:
https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d211.htm ?

For example, Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) for sparse matrices.

Comment: I used to be very involved with J for a long time, but that was years ago and my information may be out of date, so take this with the grain of salt: but during the time I was active, sparse matrices were not used much in practice, and thus didn’t get much implementation attention, and still had some sharp corners.

Comment: @DanBron Good to know -- thanks!